# Center div between two divs vertically

Tags: css

This is what I need

[image]

Is it possible to center Title between two divs which can have different size? Without JS.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
</div>
```

I checked [Stretch (vertically) middle div between the other two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847445/stretch-vertically-middle-div-between-the-other-two) but I don't know `max-height` for `header`, `footer` in my case.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Where is the CSS and complete HTML, can you provide a working snippet with the issue?

Comment: @NarenMurali I posted the answer on similar question. I can copy-paste it, but I think it doesn't have any sense, because it doesn't work for my case. And I don't know how to do it. it's why I didn't post CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what flex is for, assuming that you don't have to support older browsers.  See [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 40px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: calc(33% - 90px);
  float:left;
}
.parent:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
.parent h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.subtitle {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle<br/>Subtitle<br/>Subtitle</div>
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
   <h2>Title long<br/>2 lines</h2>
   <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Title` and `Title question` should be centered. `Subtitle` can be higher or lower

Comment: The left and right `<h2>`s are centred vertically with each other.  The middle one is pushed down slightly (like on your image) to make way for the subtitle that is twice as high.

Comment: @Jonathan, just checked https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qqpjgx. The title is not centered in the second block.

Comment: Ah, you want the block to adjust height based on the heights of all three divs so that the centre one stays centred?

Comment: The parent is fluid. Can be different height, just fixed padding. But `Title` should be centered.

Comment: @Nick, right.  And basically, the bottom div should grow to be the same height as the top subtitle div?  Like this (but obviously not hard-coded)  https://jsfiddle.net/kf6hs7hd/1/  Or should the title move up to keep the div the same height like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kf6hs7hd/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! The second one. Could you please update your answer and I'll check it.

Comment: OK, I'll try to get it so it is not hard-coded first and then update the answer.